# Iphone wireless distribution installation loop

Tags: iphone, wireless

I'm having a weird problem with iphone distribution wireless. I have placed the .ipa, .plist, and the 2 png's needed for the install. When I click on the link to install on my device and then click install the installation is in a loop. It will say installing then stop then say installing then stop and it does this forever.

Comment: Most likely a certificate or provisioning problem. I had something similar recently, which was due to signing not being correct. I don't know why I was able to build the archive without errors, but the problem didn't show up until I tried to install.

Comment: Yes, the problem was I got a new iphone and didn't add my new iphone 5c to the dist profile. Thanks!